# Specified cast is not valid. Trying to display ObservableCollection to another page using Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm trying to transfer string from `<Entry/>` on current to another page and save all strings when a button is pressed repeatedly.

My xaml on first page look like this:

```
<ImageButton Source="blackheart.png"
                    Grid.Row="1" 
                    Grid.Column="3"
                    WidthRequest="40"
                    HeightRequest="40"
                    Opacity="0.7"
                    Clicked="OnGetFavorites"/>
```

My .cs file on first page look like this:

```
void OnGetFavorites(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Preferences.Set("cityName", _cityEntry.Text);

        var tabbedPage = this.Parent.Parent as TabbedPage;

        var page = (Favorites)tabbedPage.Children[2];

        page.AddCity(_cityEntry.Text);

        tabbedPage.CurrentPage = page;
    }
```

On my second page on which I will display the xaml look like this:

```
<StackLayout Padding="0,30,0,0">

            <ListView x:Name="listView"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding CityData}"/>
</StackLayout>
```

My .cs file on second page look like this:

```
 public partial class Favorites : ContentPage
{
    ObservableCollection<string> CityData { get; set; }

    public Favorites()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

        CityData = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
    }

    public void AddCity(string city)
    {
        CityData.Add(city);
    }
}
```

When I click the button on the first page to add the strings I get an error from Main.cs file:

```
Specified cast is not valid.
```

on this line:

```
UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
```

At this step, the debugger passes: `var page = (Favorites)tabbedPage.Children[2];` But at this step the debugger makes an error: `page.AddCity(_cityEntry.Text);`

Is there a way to fix this error ?

Comment: you will need to look at the stack trace or step through the code in the debugger to narrow down the exact cause of the error

Comment: The error is  from this line: page.AddCity(_cityEntry.Text);

Comment: At this step, the debugger passes: var page = (Favorites)tabbedPage.Children[2];
But at this step the debugger makes an error: page.AddCity(_cityEntry.Text);

Comment: OK.  There are no explicit casts on that line.  Does `_cityEntry.Text` contain a valid string?  Is `page` non-null and of type `Favorites`?  You need to keep digging to determine what's wrong

Comment: I made a variable of type string: string city = _cityEntry.Text; And the debugger shows that there is a string in it..

Comment: if you want to post your code somewhere I can take a quick look.

Comment: The page is the third in a row and is accessible with a second index.

Comment: Can you check: https://github.com/GambinoRacing/WeatherLocationInfo

Comment: you need to post a solution that I can **build**.  [mcve]

Comment: Can you try now: https://github.com/GambinoRacing/WeatherLocationInfo

Comment: Nope.  There is still a huge amount missing.  There should be 2-3 separate project folders with their own csproj files and code.  You can easily verify this yourself by downloading the repo into a blank folder and trying to build it.